# Unable to update EmployeeId in ActiveDirectory via LDAP

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

I'm using Spring LDAP to create new user accounts in Active Directory.  This works fine, however when I add the EmployeeId attribute I get an javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeValueException (attribute not found).  This attribute is not visible by default, and it has been enabled in our Active Directory - I can see it the list of attributes if I do a search using a Spring LdapQuery.  Any tricks to setting EmployeeId via LDAP?  The code is straightforward, and I suspect it's going to be some AD configuration setting.

```
DirContextAdapter context = new DirContextAdapter(dn);
context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "person", "user" });
context.setAttributeValue("displayName", employee.getFullName());
context.setAttributeValue("givenName", employee.getFirstName());
context.setAttributeValue("sn", employee.getLastName());
context.setAttributeValue("cn", employee.getCn());
**context.setAttributeValue("employeeID", employee.getEmployeeID());**
context.setAttributeValue("sAMAccountName", employee.getAccountName());
...
ldapTemplate.bind(context);
```

Comment: What's the return type of `employee.getEmployeeID()`? did you have the update privilege (only Domain administrator) to add/change this value? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675662%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The account does have Domain Admin privileges.

Comment: Try to use `organizationalPerson` as additional `objectClass`. The attribute `employeeID` is an attribute of the Organizational-Person.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  I tried that as well, no change:
`'context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "person", "user", "organizationalPerson" });`

javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeValueException: Malformed 'employeeId' attribute value

Comment: Is the return type of `employee.getEmployeeID()` is `String` or maybe `null`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  The data type on the DTO was an int. Changing to a string when setting the attribute fixed the issue:

```
context.setAttributeValue("employeeId", Integer.toString(employee.getEmployeeID()));
```